# Why does scanf() stop working after the terminator character for %s in the following excerpt?

Tags: c, io, scanf

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int length, width;
    char str[3];
    // buffer size will be handled later
    scanf("/length{{%d}{%[^}]s}{%d}}", &length, str, &width);
    printf("%d %s %d", length, str, width); 
    return 0;
}
```

Please note: I don't work with C/C++ that often. Any help will be appreciated. The I/O for me personally using GCC and MSVC is:

```
# INPUT
/length{{5}{mm}{5}}

#OUTPUT
5 mm -400240432
```

Comment: What is the input string you are trying to scan?

Comment: /length{{5}{mm}{5}}

Comment: Try testing the return from `scanf`. It usually helps.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I forgot to add that in, normally the output is a number such as -82309843.  When I look it up, nothing pulls up. I will edit the question.

Comment: `{%[^}]s}` is almost certainly not what you want.  That will match any length of characters that are *not* `}` followed by a literal `s`.  Unless you actually want to match a literal `s` in the input, you just want to use `{%[^}]}`.

Answer (score 4):

The input string `/length{{5}{mm}{5}}` does not contain a literal `s`, so the format string `"/length{{%d}{%[^}]s}{%d}}"` cannot match.  You want to drop the `s` in the format string and use `"/length{{%d}{%2[^}]}{%d}}"`. Note the width modifier on the `[` conversion specifier.

This is a common error.  The `%[` portion of the format string is *not* some kind of modifier for the `%s` conversion specifier, but is its own conversion specifier.  When you write `%[...]s`, the conversion specifier ends at `]` and the `s` is treated as a literal character to be matched.